# How to calculate the integral of square of Fourier series.

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

In the proof of Bessel's inequality, I need to expand the following:
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\left[\sum_{v=1}^{n}\left( a_v\cos{vx}+b_v\sin{vx} \right)\right]^2dx}
$$
I do it like this:
$$
=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\sum_{v=1}^{n}{
\left( a_v\cos{vx}+b_v\sin{vx} \right)^2}dx}
+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{
\sum_{n=m+1}^{n}{
\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}{
2\left( a_m\cos{mx}+b_m\sin{mx} \right)
\left( a_n\cos{nx}+b_n\sin{nx} \right)
}}dx}
\\
=\sum_{v=1}^{n}{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{
\left( a_v^2\cos^2{vx}+b_v^2\sin^2{vx} +2a_vb_v\cos{vx}\sin{vx} 
\right)}dx}\\
+\sum_{n=m+1}^{n}{\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{
2a_ma_n\cos{mx}\cos{nx}}dx}}\\
+\sum_{n=m+1}^{n}{\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{
2a_mb_n\sin{nx}\cos{mx}}dx}}\\
+\sum_{n=m+1}^{n}{\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{
2a_nb_m\sin{mx}\cos{nx}}dx}}\\
+\sum_{n=m+1}^{n}{\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{
2a_nb_m\sin{mx}\cos{nx}}dx}}\\
$$
Did I do the wrong way? Or what should I do next?

Comment: Exploit the orthogonality of the sine and cosine functions.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I know the orthogonal relation in form of $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\sin{mx}\cos{nx}dx}=0$. Should I treat $a_m$, $b_n$ as a coefficient？ Or should I expand them?

Comment: You should treat them as numbers, like they are. If $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(mx)\cos(mx)\,dx=0,$$ then $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}a_m b_m \sin(mx)\cos(mx)\,dx=0,$$ what is the actual problem?

Comment: By orthogonality, the original integral simply equals $$\pi\sum_{\nu=1}^{n}(a_\nu^2+b_{\nu}^2).$$

Comment: Because $a_v=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{f(x)\cos{(vx)}dx}$.I'm not sure whether to expand them with the equation.

Comment: What would be the purpose of expanding them? You know the orthogonality relations, so exploit them and express the original integral in terms of $a_n$ and $b_m$, without expanding them as integrals (in your actual question, they are not defined by integrals, they are just numbers)

Comment: If treat them as number, then I'm clearly.Thank you.